# How to make a loop in csv file?

Tags: python, html, csv

I don't want line1, line2 and so on to be written again and again. How to make a loop in it so that I don't have to write every time? I tried but fail.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

csv_file = open('filo.csv','r')
csv_file = csv_file.readlines()
line1 = csv_file[0]
line1 = line1.split(',')
line2 = csv_file[1]
line2 = line2.split(',')
x = PrettyTable([line1[0],line2[0]]) 
for a in range(1, len(line1)):
    x.add_row([line1[a], line2[a]])
html_code = x.get_html_string()
html_file = open('table.html','w')
html_file = html_file.write(html_code)
```

Comment: Drink a few coffees and write a CSV compiler/interpreter first :)

Comment: you should really consider using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), it can get the .csv file name, and read it to a table that also prints nicely

Comment: you can also use [to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) to write the table to html

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two keys to answering your immediate question. The first is Python's s `zip()` function, which takes a sequence of sequences and interleaves them. For example:

```
>>> list(zip((1,2,3), (4,5,6)))
[(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
```

The second key is that in Python, you can pass a sequence of arguments to a function by preceding it with an asterisk ('*'). For example:

```
>>> def add(*args):
       return sum(args)
>>> add(1,2,3)
6
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> add(*numbers)
6
```

These two keys together let you eliminate most of your  awkward line1, line2 constructs.

```
csv_file = open('filo.csv','r')
csv_file = csv_file.readlines()
line1 = csv_file[0].split(',')
line2 = csv_file[1].split'(',')

interleaved = list(zip(line1, line2)) 
x = PrettyTable(*interleaved[0])    
for pair in interleaved[1:]:
    x.add_row(*pair)
# Then go on to generate and write HTML code, as before.
```

This should solve your immediate problem. In addidtion,you might want to rewrite the opening and reading of the file using the  `with` statement, and the parsing of the file using [Python's `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It will make your code cleaner and more robust.

```
import csv
from prettytable import PrettyTable

with open('filo.csv') as csv_file:
    myreader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    interleaved = list(zip(next(myreader), next(myreader)))
    x = PrettyTable(*interleaved[0])
   for pair in interleaved[1:]:
        x.add_row(*pair)
# and so forth.
```

There you go! The "line1" and "line2" stuff is gone altogether.

Fair warning: I didn't test any of this code against csv data, so you you will probably have to clean it up somewhat. But at least it should point you in the right direction.